# Undefined variable when trying to pass data to the view - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I'm trying to include a view on all of my pages (code is below), so I've included it within my layout template (so it renders on everything). Unfortunately, when I try and run any page - this error occurs:

> Undefined variable: sites (View:
>   /Users/Documents/audit/resources/views/layouts/check.blade.php)

**View (check.blade.php):**

```
@if (count($sites) == 0)
 // Removed as it is irrelevant.
@endif
```

**Controller:**

```
public function siteCheck()
{
  return View::make('layouts.check')
                  ->with('sites', Site::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                  ->get());
}
```

**Where I try and include the view (which shows the error):**

```
@if(!Auth::guest())
  @include('layouts.check')
@endif
```

N.B. I haven't added any code relating to the layouts.check page within the routes.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that when You include file `layouts.check` method `siteCheck()` isn't launched (and therefore varaible $sites don't exist).

**You have couple of options:**

1. **add a variable when incuding file**

`@include('layouts.check', ['sites' => $sites])`
(Still You will need to pass `$sites` from the contoller tho the master view.)

2. **add view composer which add this variable every time the view will be included**

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

In Your case it would look like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('layouts.check', function ($view) {

        $view->with('sites', Site::where('user_id', Auth::id())
              ->get());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
@if(isset($sites)&&count($sites) == 0)
 // Removed as it is irrelevant.
@endif
```

**NOTE:**

whene you use `@include('layouts.check')` you not set `$sites`